# What does a utc replace do on a utc timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have come across the following code:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tzutc())
```

I can't see what the replace() call is doing, from reading the docs it seems to convert it into a UTC timestamp - but surely utcnow() would return a UTC timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
# returns datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 10, 39, 1, 303329)
```

gives you the current datetime in UTC without `tzinfo` information:

```
.replace(tzinfo=tzutc())
# returns datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 10, 39, 1, 303329, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

adds this tzinfo information to the datetime object.

You can get the same (current datetime in UTC with UTC tzinfo) using:

```
datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
# returns datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 4, 10, 39, 1, 303329, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 0):

This just calls [`datetime.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace), this particular usage is mentioned a lot on that documentation page.

It's useful since `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` returns a  `datetime` without time zone information (`tzinfo` will be `None`): the `replace()` call is used to change that.